Parallelism with recursion with python
I'm working on a Python project where I need to explore different positions recursively, and I want to parallelize this process using ProcessPoolExecutor.
What I Want to Achieve:
In my project, I need to create a pool of subprocesses at the beginning of the execution. I know in advance that I will need no more than 20 subprocesses, but at any given depth of recursion, I will only use at 2 more of them. The goal is to pre-create all 20 subprocesses at the start and then allocate them as needed during the exploration process, based on the depth of the recursion.
Here is my code were I create a new process as I go and it works but the overhead is too large.
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import multiprocessing
import time

def explore(position, depth=0, max_depth=3):
    print(f"Process {multiprocessing.current_process().pid}: Exploring position {position} at depth {depth}")

    if depth < max_depth:
        new_positions = [
            (position[0] + 1, position[1]), 
            (position[0], position[1] + 1)
        ]

        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(new_positions)) as executor:
            futures = [executor.submit(explore, pos, depth + 1, max_depth) for pos in new_positions]

            for future in futures:
                future.result()

        print(f"Process {multiprocessing.current_process().pid}: Additional processing after future.result()")
        time.sleep(0.1)

    return position

if __name__ == "__main__":
    initial_position = (0, 0)

    start_time = time.time()
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        future = executor.submit(explore, initial_position)
        result = future.result()

    print("Exploration complete.")
    print("Time taken:", time.time() - start_time)


I'm not sure why using recursion? Just create pool with e.g. 20 workers and send/receive data from/to using queues.

You forgot to write any question (you just wrote statements). Why do you say that the overhead is too large? You think it should be faster? At a quick glance the creating ProcessPoolExecutors recursively seems like a bad idea... you'd probably want to create that once (with you 20 threads if I understood you correctly), and then use that single pool (I think Andrej Kesely is also referring to this).
